# How to write an Oracle procedure with a select statement (Specifically on SQL Developer)?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to create a simple Oracle Stored procedure on SQL Developer that will return some records on a  simple select query. I do not want to pass in any parameter, but I just want the Records to be returned back from the procedure into a result set -> a suitable variable.

I have been trying to use the following syntax :

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Getmarketdetails2(data OUT varchar2)
IS
BEGIN

  SELECT *
  into data
  from  dual;

END Getmarketdetails2;
```

**But it gives me an error while I try to execute with the following exec statement** -->

```
Declare a Varchar2;
exec Getmarketdetails2(a);
```

**Error:** PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting "something else".

**Cause:**    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.

Appreciate if anyone can help me out of this long pending situation! I have tried enough to find a basic guide to create a simple Oracle stored procedure and execute it in SQL Developer, but none of them answer to the point!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want:

```
DECLARE
  a VARCHAR2(4000);          -- Give it a size
BEGIN                        -- Begin the anonymous PL/SQL block
  Getmarketdetails2(a);      -- Call the procedure
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( a ); -- Output the value
END;                         -- End the anonymous PL/SQL block
/                            -- End the PL/SQL statement
```

or:

```
VARIABLE a VARCHAR2(4000);   -- Create a bind variable
EXEC Getmarketdetails2(:a);  -- Execute the procedure using the bind variable
PRINT a                      -- Print the bind variable
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming an up-to-date Oracle version, you can use `dbms_sql.return_result()`

```
create or replace PROCEDURE Getmarketdetails2
IS
  c1 SYS_REFCURSOR;  
BEGIN

  OPEN c1 FOR 
  SELECT *
  from  dual;
  DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(c1);

END Getmarketdetails2;
/
```

Then simply run

```
exec Getmarketdetails2
```

---

The only drawback is that SQL Developer only displays the result as text, not as a proper result grid.

Comment: It throws me an error -->  **PLS-00302: component 'RETURN_RESULT' must be declared**

Comment: @sanrns: then you are not using an up-to-date Oracle version

Answer (score 1):

This is how I return a cursor in Oracle

```
PROCEDURE GetAllData (P_CURSOR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN

  OPEN P_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT *
    FROM TABLE ;

END GetAllData ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare a Varchar2; 
exec Getmarketdetails2(a);
```

Your procedure is ok;
Instead of above query, use below query to run sp:

```
Declare 
  a Varchar2(10); 
Begin
  Getmarketdetails2(a);
End;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this execute one by one statement is working on my end.

```
create or replace procedure sp_test(c1 out SYS_REFCURSOR)    
as    
begin  
open c1 for  
select * from user_details;  
end sp_test; 

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;  
variable mycursor refcursor;  
exec sp_test (:mycursor);  
print mycursor;
```

output:

```
 USER_ID   USER_NAME                                         
--------- ----------
       1   anita                                             
       2   dinesh                                            
       3   sagar
```